# Two LineSeries with the same Y Axis in WPF Toolkit charts

Tags: charts, wpftoolkit, data-visualization

I want to do the following with the WPF toolkit charts:

I have two line series that should use the same y axis (i.e I want them both to be on the same scale).  I could give each of them the same axis definition so they would overlap (and then have one of them with collapsed visibility), but that is not my best choice.

This is the solution I'm talking about:

```
<charts:LineSeries Name="ExternalMeasureSeries"
               IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Time}"
               DependentValueBinding="{Binding ExternalMeasure}">
    <charts:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <Style TargetType="charts:LineDataPoint">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </charts:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <!-- Vertical axis for external measure curve -->
    <charts:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
        <charts:LinearAxis
            Orientation="Y"
            Title="Measurement"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="30"/>
    </charts:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
</charts:LineSeries>
<charts:LineSeries Name="InternalMeasureSeries"
                   IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Time}"
                   DependentValueBinding="{Binding InternalMeasure}">
    <charts:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <Style TargetType="charts:LineDataPoint">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </charts:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <!-- Vertical axis for internal measure curve -->
    <charts:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
        <charts:LinearAxis
            Orientation="Y"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="30"
            Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </charts:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
</charts:LineSeries>
```

Is there a way to define more than one series with the same Y axis?

I found that toolkit version 3.5.0.0 has something called `StackedLineSeries` but that version 3.5.40128.1 which is what gets installed in the February 2010 version of the toolkit, it isn't there.  Did it move to another clr-namespace?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and found the following way around. You can add the two series to the same chart and hide the second series Axis label by setting the Width to 0;

```
<charts:LinearAxis
Orientation="Y"
Title="Measurement"
Minimum="0"
Maximum="30"
**Width = "0"**
/>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I have a chart with 3 line series. The first 2 series represent the relative humidity and the third one represent the dew point. 
I want to draw the first 2 series on the same Y axis. I created my axes in a resource section. In my example, this is in a `TabItem`.

```
<TabItem Header="rH">
<TabItem.Resources>
    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="rH /%" x:Key="RHYAxis" />
    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Title="Dew point /°C" x:Key="DewPointYAxis" />
</TabItem.Resources>
<chartingToolkit:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Title="Relative Humidity" IsEnabled="True">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentRangeAxis="{StaticResource RHYAxis}" IsSelectionEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RHCollection}" IndependentValuePath="TimeStamp" DependentValuePath="rH" Title="Measured rH" />
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentRangeAxis="{StaticResource RHYAxis}" IsSelectionEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CorrectedRHCollection}" IndependentValuePath="TimeStamp" DependentValuePath="CorrectedRH" Title="Corrected rH" />
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentRangeAxis="{StaticResource DewPointYAxis}" IsSelectionEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DewPointCollection}" IndependentValuePath="TimeStamp" DependentValuePath="DewPoint" Title="Dew point" />
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```