# WPF Charting : Display text vertically on Y axis

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

In my chart I want to display text before Y axis as a vertical Title in center for y axis like "% Volume" and below X axis in center want to display label as "Sales". How do I add these labels on X & Y axis respectively ? My XML code is :

```
Grid>
    <DVC:Chart Name="bsiPlaceChart" Title="SI Placement" LegendTitle="Legend" Width="850" Height="450">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:ColumnSeries Name="layer1Chart" Title="Title 1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IndependentValuePath="Name"
                           DependentValuePath="Volume"></DVC:ColumnSeries>

            <DVC:ColumnSeries Name="layer2Chart" Title="Title 2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IndependentValuePath="Name"
                           DependentValuePath="Volume" ></DVC:ColumnSeries>

            <DVC:ColumnSeries Name="layer3Chart" Title="Title 3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IndependentValuePath="Name"
                           DependentValuePath="Volume" ></DVC:ColumnSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Layers" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="343,440,472,0" />

</Grid>
```

For X axis, I tried adding a text block below the chart, but when window size changes, the text also moves up and down. I wan it to stay below the chart - as if it is part of the chart.

How do I set such titles for X & Y axis respectively.

**UPDATIONS :
Solution Provided by Paul :**
I added in Resources for X & Y axis respectively :

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="% Volume" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Key="YAxis" />
    <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="Layers" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Key="XAxis" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

And in each Column series modified as below :

```
<DVC:ColumnSeries Name="layer1Chart" Title="Viscosity 1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IndependentValuePath="Name" DependentValuePath="Volume" DependentRangeAxis="{StaticResource YAxis}">
</DVC:ColumnSeries>
```

This managed the Y axis point. How do I add the XAxis also to it ?

**SOLUTION** :
Removed the resources and added Chart.Axes in Chart as shown below. This adds "% Volume" label on left of Y Axis and "Layers" label on bottom of X Axis. Perfect.

```
 <!-- Add Title on Y axis and X Axis -->
 <DVC:Chart.Axes>
       <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="% Volume" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
       <DVC:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Title="Layers" Location="Bottom" />
</DVC:Chart.Axes>
```

Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should do it:

```
<charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
    <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y"  Title="Y Axis"/>
</charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
```

Have a read of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645563/two-lineseries-with-the-same-y-axis-in-wpf-toolkit-charts) and of this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791639/linearaxis-without-decimal-numbers)

EDIT: Taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225465/labels-on-chart-toolkit-wpf), to set the x and y axis do something like the following

```
<charting:Chart.Axes>
  <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y">
     <charting:LinearAxis.Title>
          <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource YAxisTitleContentTemplate}"/>
     </charting:LinearAxis.Title>
  </charting:LinearAxis>
  <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X">
       <charting:CategoryAxis.Title>
           <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource XAxisTitleContentTemplate}"/>
       </charting:CategoryAxis.Title>
  </charting:CategoryAxis>
</charting:Chart.Axes>
```

For the X axis only:

```
<charting:Chart.Axes>
   <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Title="The X Axis Title" />
</charting:Chart.Axes>
```

Comment: The above 1st link helped me write title on the Y axis. I added in resources & set the DependentRangeAxis property to the resource. In that I can add only 1 key; where as I have different for X & Y axis. How do I set the same for X axis ??